# What is the Green's function of the Klein-Gordon equation with a variable mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, propagator

1. Usually, the Klein-Gordon equation's propagator is calculated with a constant mass. But what if the mass is a variable? That is,
   $$ (-\partial^2 + m(x)^2)G(x, y) = \delta^4(x-y)$$ where $m(x)$ is a function of the position four-vector.
2. Also, I would like to know the Lagrangian which leads up to this equation. Is it the same as given below?
   $$ L = -\frac{1}{2} \partial^{\mu}\phi\partial_{\mu}\phi - \frac{1}{2}\phi^2 m(x)^2$$ where $m(x)$ is the same as above.

Comment: Variable masses usually appear when trying to do QFT in curved space, e.g. the "mass" that appears for a scalar particle in FLRW space is time-dependent, so no, that Lagrangian there is not where one usually gets the variable mass from. Aside from that, are you "just" asking for the explicit solution for the Green's function of KG with variable mass, or is there a conceptual question here?

Comment: I would suggest searching one of the many "databases" which list most known Green's functions

Comment: @ACuriousMind    Yes, I want an explicit solution. Why ? That I cannot tell you, sorry. Also, can you tell me the Lagrangian which leads up to such an equation ?

Comment: @Qmechanic  homework-and-exercise ? Really ? Some people ask questions because they are working on something. Maybe a new theory or a new formalism, you know.

Comment: Hi user44690. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.